# Trigger the lambda with dynamodb when a specific entry is registered

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I need to trigger a lambda when a specific object registers on DynamoDB.

For example:

> If I create a `User` with a `POST /my-website/user` and, I store this `User` on `DynamoDB`, I want to trigger
> my `Lambda`.
>
> I don't want to trigger the `Lambda` if the registered object is
> different from the `User`.

[image]

For the management of my stack, I use `Serverless` (with a `serverless.yml` file) and `CloudFormation` syntax.

With the serverless documentation, I can't figure out how I can trigger my `Lambda` only when a specific entry is registered to `DynamoDB` ( https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/streams ).

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:

Thank you for your answers :)

It's work:

```
  statement:
    handler: lambda/statement.php
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:<account_id>:layer:php-73:1
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:ListStreams
          - dynamodb:GetItem
    events:
    - stream:
        type: dynamodb
        arn: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-3:<account_id>:table/dev-project/stream/2020-11-18T22:34:01.579
        maximumRetryAttempts: 1
        batchSize: 1
        filterPatterns:
          - eventName: [INSERT]
            dynamodb:
              NewImage:
                __partitionKey:
                  S: [myPk]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup [stream filters](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/filtering-event-sources-for-aws-lambda-functions/). The process is explained in:

- [NEW: DynamoDB Streams Filtering in Serverless Framework](https://dev.to/aws-builders/new-dynamodb-streams-filtering-in-serverless-framework-3lc5)

Comment: They are called event filtering as they can filter more than just streams. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html

Comment: Thank both :)

I edited my post thanks to your help but I still have a sticking point.

Answer (score 1):

You attach the DynamoDB stream event onto the lambda in your serverless file in the function's "events" sections. https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-dynamodb-stream-to-lamba-function

If you're creating the Dynamo table using serverless, you could output the table's StreamArn as a stack variable.
https://carova.io/snippets/serverless-aws-cloudformation-output-stack-variables

If they're in the same file, you don't need the Output section, you could just set the "events" sections of the lambda and reference

arn: { Fn::GetAtt: [DynamoTable, StreamArn] }

in the arn section of the specific event.

Comment: Thank's for your article! :)
Added to favorites

Answer (score 0):

Stream Filters worked (thank you). Here's the final configuration:

```
  statement:
    handler: lambda/statement.php
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:<account_id>:layer:php-73:1
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:ListStreams
          - dynamodb:GetItem
    events:
    - stream:
        type: dynamodb
        arn: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-3:<account_id>:table/dev-project/stream/2020-11-18T22:34:01.579
        maximumRetryAttempts: 1
        batchSize: 1
        filterPatterns:
          - eventName: [INSERT]
            dynamodb:
              NewImage:
                __partitionKey:
                  S: [myPk]
```